# PHP merge single array elements into unique array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm not sure how to work the title of this question, so sorry if it's a little confusing.

I have an array;

```
  Array
  (
      [username] => Array
          (
              [0] => 'a'
              [1] => 'b'
              [2] => 'c'
              [3] => 'd'
              [4] => 'e'
              [5] => 'f'
          )

      [email] => Array
          (
              [0] => 
              [1] => 
              [2] => 
              [3] => 
              [4] => 
              [5] => 
          )

      [level] => Array
          (
              [0] => 1
              [1] => 1
              [2] => 1
              [3] => 1
              [4] => 1
              [5] => 1
          )

      [role] => Array
          (
              [0] => 2
              [1] => 1
              [2] => 1
              [3] => 1
              [4] => 2
              [5] => 1
          )

      [password] => Array
          (
              [0] => 
              [1] => 
              [2] => 
              [3] => 
              [4] => 
              [5] => 
          )

      [id] => Array
          (
              [0] => 1
              [1] => 2
              [2] => 3
              [3] => 4
              [4] => 5
              [5] => 6
          )

  )
```

But I want it in this format:

```
  Array
  (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [username] => 'a'
              [id] => 'a'
              [email] => 'a'
          )
      [1] => Array
          (
              [username] => 'a'
              [id] => 'a'
              [email] => 'a'
          )
      [2] => Array
          (
              [username] => 'a'
              [id] => 'a'
              [email] => 'a'
          )
      [3] => Array
          (
              [username] => 'a'
              [id] => 'a'
              [email] => 'a'
          )
      [4] => Array
          (
              [username] => 'a'
              [id] => 'a'
              [email] => 'a'
          )
      [5] => Array
          (
              [username] => 'a'
              [id] => 'a'
              [email] => 'a'
          )
```

I can't seem to figure it out, arrays end too soon, or there ends up being too many indexes etc. Ideas?

Comment: Is this returned data, or an array that you're generating? Please provide the code that generates (if it's the latter).

Comment: It's returned data from a `json_decode` so there is no actual PHP array structure.

Comment: Why not loop through it and reconstruct the array?

Comment: What do you mean? To get it out for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would loop through the array and reconstruct it like so:

```
$index_count = count($array['username']); // in your case, this is 6

$new_array = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $index_count; $i++) {
    $new_array[] = array(
        'username' => $array['username'][$i],
        'email' => $array['email'][$i],
        'id' => $array['id'][$i]
    );
}
```

**UPDATE** If you want this to take into consideration *any and all possible keys*, try this:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
if (count($keys)) {
    $index_count = count($array[$keys[0]]);

    $myArray = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $index_count; $i++) {
        $temp = array();
        foreach($keys as $key) {
            $temp[$key] = $array[$key][$i];
        }
        $myArray[] = $temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really need the keys to be dynamic though, there are many more and they could change at any time, so I shouldn't need to have to enter them manually - I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Indeed. Everything that is entered.

Comment: It's cool! I've sorted it.
foreach($PL as $keyKey => $keyValue) {
     foreach($keyValue as $key => $val) {
      $rowPerUser[$key][$keyKey] = $val;
      // echo $keyKey;
     }
    }

Answer (score 1):

A different take, but here's what I would do - step by step:

First, let's get the keys - we'll be needing them a lot:

```
$result = array();//<-- this is the result array
$keys = array_keys($array);
```

Then, I'd get an empty, *template* array (somewhat like a model object)

```
$base = array_fill_keys($keys,array());
//array('username'=>array,'id'=>array(),...
```

Then, use that to build your result array:

```
$result = array_fill(0,count($array['username']),$base);
//In one-liner format, it looks like this:
$result = array_fill(0,count($array['username']),array_fill_keys(array_keys($array),array()));
//Works, but is messy as f***
```

Then just fill the lot, this is where that `$keys` variable pays off:

```
$length = count($result);
while ($key = array_shift($keys))
{
    for ($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
    {
        $result[$i][$key] = $array[$key][$i];
    }
}
```

Note that I prefer using a while loop, as it is cleaner and (marginally) faster. Cleaner because that `$keys` array is being emptied as you go along. If you're working with substantial amounts of data it can sometimes make a difference. If the dataset is *REALLY* large, and the code has been thoroughly tested, you might even want to consider `shifting` from the source array (as it contains all data, it's a lot bigger than a an array containing just the keys):

```
while ($vals = array_shift($array))
{
    $key = array_shift($keys);//<-- keep track of what array has been shifted
    for ($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
    {
        $result[$i][$key] = $vals[$i];
    }
}
```

This neatly cleans up the source array, and the keys. I've tested this last approach on my server, writecodeonline and codepad, all with exactly the same results:

```
$foo = array('bar'=>array_fill(0,2,'ás'),'quar'=>range('a','z'));
$keys = array_keys($foo);
while($vals = array_shift($foo))
{
    $key = array_shift($keys);
    echo $key.' contains: => '.implode(', ',$vals).'<br/>';
}
```

> bar contains: => ás, ás
>
> quar contains: => a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z